# MongoDB like(upvote) and dislike(downvote) schema design

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I was [going through this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421164/insert-if-not-exists-else-remove-mongodb) then I saw the code below:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53f51a844ffa9b02cf01c074"),
    "upvoted": [],
    "downvoted": [],
    "upvoteCount": 0,
    "downvoteCount": 0
}
```

I have somewhat a similar schema without the vote counts. Like you can see below.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53f51a844ffa9b02cf01c074"),
    "upvoted": [],
    "downvoted": [],
}
```

What is the advantage of having the count fields? Why not [get the length of the embedded array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253590/how-to-find-length-of-embedded-nested-array-in-mongodb) when you need to get the vote count? Does it help in performance(when you only want to query a voteCount)?

Comment: you don't really need the count fields. i'm sure it will save a couple of millisecond when querying multi-million document collections. only testing will tell for sure. also, if you're looking for a single update query that can take care of upvote/downvote logic, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60469900/mongodb-comment-upvoting-downvoting-with-aggregation-pipeline/60472539#60472539

Comment: There is no need to store number of counts in a separate field. Keeping this up-to-date and consistent is more effort than simply using the `$size` operator.